# Can't Load laravel Project in Xampp /lampp (MAC)

Tags: php, laravel, installation, xampp, lampp

iam installed laravel project using laravel documents details.and installed my project into my lampp directory path (**htdocs/myproject**).After that i run my project in browser.But i didt get the intro page of laravel showing **Permission denied** messege Like:
`The stream or file "/opt/lampp/htdocs/dotgo/storage/logs/laravel.log" could not be opened in append mode: Failed to open stream: Permission denied`
given all permissions to the laravel project folder by using the following command:

```
chmod 777 dotgo
```

Still i cant run the project file.Any one please help me to solve this one.....

Comment: `chmod -R  775  storage` inside project DIR

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Have you checked the permissions of that file?

Answer (score 0):

try this `chmod ugo+ rwx “lampp”` inside your lampp dir